# SequelizeDatabaseError: column \"functionCode\" does not exist, when it does

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgresql-11

I am writing a simple NodeJS code to read/write from/to postgres using sequelize. My code works for one table but the similar code breaks when tested for another unrelated table. I also find the error thrown confusing as can be seen from the error stack trace.

I disabled timestamp columns and executed the SQL on CLI which sequelize has problem with.

First, this is the model in /**tfnMetadata.js**

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Model definition: See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html
 *  See DataTypes: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/data-types.html
 * @param
 * @returns {*} records.
 */
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const tfnMetadata = sequelize.define('tfn_metadata', {
    did: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false,
    },
    dnis: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    functionCode: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    language: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    coBrand: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    collections: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    smallBusiness: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    welcomeMessageCode: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    welcomeMessage: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },
    referenceKey: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    partner: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, { timestamps: false, tableName: 'tfn_metadata' });
  tfnMetadata.sync({ alter: true });
  return tfnMetadata;
};
```

The corresponding schema of the table in psql is:

```
       Column       |          Type          | Nullable | 
--------------------+------------------------+----------+
 did                | character varying(15)  | not null |
 dnis               | character varying(15)  |          |
 functioncode       | character varying(20)  |          |
 country            | character varying(25)  |          |
 language           | character varying(20)  |          |
 cobrand            | boolean                |          |
 collections        | boolean                |          |
 smallbusiness      | boolean                |          |
 welcomemessagecode | text                   |          |
 welcomemessage     | character varying(200) |          |
 referencekey       | character varying(50)  |          |
 partner            | character varying(50)
```

Then there is standard NodeJS code (`./models/index`) that reads the model definition files to import the models. Edit - This is the only code I didn't provide but it is almost same as given here: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/articles/express/

The query is executed in **query.js** file using following function:

```js
const models = require('./models/index');

const getByPk = async (didNumber) => {
  try {
    const record = await models.tfnMetadata.findByPk(didNumber.toString());
    logger.info('Query.getByPk() Returned the record from db.', record);
    return record.dataValues;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Query.getByPk() failed:', err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The above code is invoked in client.js as-

```js
const query = require('../../src/clients/pg/query');
const tfnData = await query.getByPk(did);
```

But it fails with -

```
Query.getByPk() Request to get record for did=111 undefined
Query.getByPk() failed: {
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 184,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "hint": "Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"tfn_metadata.functioncode\".",
    "position": "23",
    "file": "parse_relation.c",
    "line": "3294",
    "routine": "errorMissingColumn",
    "sql": "SELECT \"did\", \"dnis\", \"functionCode\", \"country\", \"language\", \"coBrand\", \"collections\", \"smallBusiness\", \"welcomeMessageCode\", \"welcomeMessage\", \"referenceKey\", \"partner\" FROM \"tfn_metadata\" AS \"tfn_metadata\" WHERE \"tfn_metadata\".\"did\" = '111';"
  }
error: End - Error:
error: {
    "errorMessage": "column \"functionCode\" does not exist",
    "errorType": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Query.formatError (/Users/.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:354:16)",
        "query.catch.err (/Users/.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:71:18)",
        "tryCatcher (/Users/.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
        "Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)",
```

The error code indicates undefined column or missing column `functionCode` and hint is asking if I am meant to refer the `functionCode`.

Comment: `"functionCode"` is a different name than `functioncode` you should remove the double quotes from your SQL string - none of your columns require to be quoted. Use: `"sql": "SELECT did, dnis, functionCode, country, language, coBrand, collections, smallBusiness ... FROM tfn_metadata WHERE tfn_metadata.did = '111';"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The only place where I have typed functionCode is in model definition and postgres makes all the column names lower case as seen in the table schema printed. Secondly, the sql string printed in the error stack is the sql ORM package has created, I am not passing it or creating it. Interestingly when I execute the same sql from Postgres client (after removing \”), the query works. So, it’s confusing where it’s getting wrong column name, if at all there is one.

Comment: @Vish you aren't including all the code or you have changed it since you generated the schema - I can tell because the log message in your question doesn't match the code in the `query.js` you provided.

Comment: @doublesharp I didn't exclude any code. However, I did include the reference or missing code which, I think, makes no difference to the understanding of the code and hence was not added in the original post. I ran the code again and got the same error stack.

Comment: use lowercase or underscores names for the tables, not camel cases.

Comment: @ArpitPandey I was about to update with the same. I changed model fields to lower case and it worked. You can add answer and I can accept it. I am trying to figure if there is a way to have model in camcelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lowercases or underscores for the names of the table fields, not camelCase

Comment: The model fields can be defined in camelCase or any case if they also have field attribute that has value of the actual column name. And the column names in pg are in lowercase. So - ```json  functionCode: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: 'functioncode',
    } ```